# Update statement errors, parenthesis, failed validation ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

i am writing an update query and it is giving me errors, what i am trying to do is to take a value multiply it added to another value.

**Original statement**

The statement below works flawlessly,

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

**Modified version not working**
This is the modified version,  i want to multiply the first two select with a value in each field for in flight and outfight seats no.

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL(((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0)) +
   NVL(((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0)* NVL(R.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0)) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

Comment: These are DML statements, not triggers.

Comment: yes indeed, i forgot to update the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NVL` takes at least two parameters. But the `NVL`s at the beginning on the line have only one.

You probably want:

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0)* NVL(R.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

Next time, please add the error message to the question.